# MATLAB LU decomposition not responding

Tags: matlab

I have a lower triangular matrix (L) and an upper triangular matrix (U). I use mldivide to find the solution of `L*U*x = b`. I think that MATLAB is smart enough to find out that only backward/forward substitution is needed. But I feel it would even faster if I can tell matlab (somehow) that only forward/backward substitution should be carried out.

Kindly let me know how I can tell MATLAB to just do backward/forward substitution and no extra operation is needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html#brs10rz-1) are pretty clear:

> **Permutations of Triangular Matrices**
>
> mldivide checks for triangularity
>   by testing for zero elements. If a matrix A is triangular, MATLAB
>   software uses a substitution to compute the solution vector x. If A is
>   a permutation of a triangular matrix, MATLAB software uses a permuted
>   substitution algorithm.

so

```
x = U \ (L \ b);
```

is the backward/forward solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Searching the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html) it seems like Matlab does indeed use backward/forward substitution. However, since `mldivide` gets the matrix `L*U` and not `L` and `U` separately, it has to perform the decomposition internally.

If you already have the L and U matrices you may be able to save that part of the calculation.